# how to load opencv object to face_recognition. load_image_file() api does not work for this

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, dlib

repost of my question here: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/441

I would like to load an opencv image object into face_recognition library.
https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition

I am using Django Python, I have used opencv to crop and do some face quality checks.

Here is what something I did:

```
im_obj = request.data['image_file']
im_cv = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(im_obj.read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
result, checked_cv_image = process(im_cv) <-- this does some stuff like crop, etc

unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(checked_cv_image) <-- this doesnt work
```

it has this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

My Question:

I would like to know is it possible to figure a way how to load an opencv object into face_recognition object.

UPDATE:

I tried to use, this:

```
ret, buf_checked_cv_image = cv2.imencode( '.png', checked_cv_image )
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(buf_checked_cv_image)
```

this doesnt work as well, same error:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/face_recognition/api.py#L75) of that function says the following about the first parameter: "file: image file name or file object to load". A `numpy.array` is neither. Not sure why you would want to call it anyway, it just uses PIL to load (and decode) the file into a `numpy.array` and returns it to you. The functions that do the processing take a `numpy.array` as input...

Comment: At most you may have to swap the blue and red channels, since IIRC PIL will load colour images as RGB, but OpenCV loads them as BGR.

Comment: i have a team member that tries do certain validation of the image, thats the reason why they are using opencv. but it returns an opencv object. i tried doing this but it doesnt work https://gist.github.com/axilaris/8775833d63b1c7f70c5cbc6fb7bf9698

Comment: No, the Python bindings of OpenCV use a `numpy.array` to represent the images. There's absolutely no reason to call `face_recognition.load_image_file`, when you already have the image in memory.

Comment: the reason for load image is to do face_recognition using this library https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition. i am planning to use face_recognition.compare_faces

Comment: Why don't you take a minute [read the source code](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/face_recognition/api.py#L75) of that function (including the doc comment), and then look at a few of the ones that do the processing. IMHO it's rather obvious, and I don't see a reason to repeat it any further.

Comment: thanks!!! i didnt see that. let me try

Comment: im_cv variable you already have. This is all you need.